# Access - Multiple Records in a Form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'll create an fictitious example to explain what I am trying to accomplish.

Let's say I have these tables as fields:

- Reports

  - idReport
  - date
- FieldsList

  - idField
  - nameField
- FieldsValues

  - idReport
  - idField
  - value

So, this works like this:
One report has many fields. Each field has an value.
Here are some sample data:

Reports

```
idReport | date
1 | 04/04/14
2 | 10/06/14
```

FieldsList

```
idField | nameField
1 | serialNumber
2 | manufacturer
3 | model
```

FieldsValues

```
idReport | idField | value
1 | 1 | FSI83618A
1 | 2 | Apple
1 | 3 | A1457
```

What I want to do is an form where the user select an Report and I'll show every row in the FieldValues table for that report, this way:

FieldsList.nameFiled: FieldsValues.value

Is that clear?

I found a way to do this using Datasheet form, or continuous form, but that is not what I really want.
I want to be able do "design" the screen, put every field where I want, the way I want.
If I use datasheet, it just makes an table and I can't change it.

Anyone have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO you can solve this in 2 different ways, it's just a matter of "taste" what suit's you more as GUI

1. Form with subform
   Form contains the reports and subform contains values/fieldnames (you have to combine the 2 tables in a query), make the subform depending on the key in main form
2. make an unbound form, place 2 listboxes
   Listbox on the left shows the reports, listbox on the right shows values/fieldnames (same query as above) per Report. When selecting the report, you fire the "after update" event to filter the listbox at the right
   This solution needs a bit of coding

Answer (score 0):

Continuous form is the right solution: You can choose where you want to put the field title and where to put the field value.

Of course, if you want *different fields* at *different locations*, i.e. if you want the positions to depend on the *data*, then I'm afraid that you have chosen the wrong table design. Access is not designed for this. If you want that, Access expects the table to be laid out like this:

- Reports

  - idReport
  - date
  - serialNumber
  - manufacturer
  - model

If you have an existing legacy data structure that you cannot change, you can create a *query* that will transform your data into that format. Note, however, that you won't be able to *change* data in the form if you base it on such a query, which is fine if you only want to display it, but won't solve your problem if you want to edit it.

If you need to be able to *edit* such data, you will have to do the work yourself: Create an unbound form and manually perform the INSERTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs in code. The problem is that Access expects an *edit* in a field to be an UPDATE. However, in your case, an *edit* could be an INSERT (if no `FieldValues` row existed before) or a DELETE. Thus, the built-in tools won't do much good.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was using the wrong tool to do what I want.

Since I just want to display informations, I managed to do what I want using reports.

So I created an Form and a report based on a consultation (I'm sorry, I don't know how it's called in english office. I use my office in portuguese).

In this form I choose the report number. When I click a button, I "requery" the report window that is embed in this form.
In this report window I have some freedom to work with the design.
The listed fields are still just like a list, but it's much better than that datasheet layout.

Thank you for your help.